# Does open query windows in SSMS affect performance issue on Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

We have a senior developer who claimes that open query windows in SSMS affects performance on SQL Server. Is that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the query windows are open but not doing anything they will be classed as inactive sessions and consume minimal resources. Depending on your systems use you may see lots of these even hundreds but I wouldn't be concerned.

if you run this it will show you all connected users (exclude system processes)
select * from sys.sysprocesses
where spid > 50

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1257229-1550-1.aspx

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/b23178b3-343e-4066-99de-367a11f664fe/idle-connections-problem-or-not